# How to reshape three-dimentional arrays into two-dimentional arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have training and testing data arrays that are 3 dimensional and I am trying to convert them into 2-dimensional arrays. I've tried to use the .reshape() function but it is not working.
The arrays shape are as follow:
Training:(60000, 28, 28) 47040000
Test:(10000, 28, 28) 7840000
I already rescaled the integer values

I would appreciate some guidance as I am quite new to python.

Comment: Show what you've done and an actual workable example with inputs and outputs. "It does not work" does not constitute a valid problem statement.

Comment: Also, please use proper formatting and add a plain python tag to your question. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57771426/edit) button underneath to add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```py
arr = np.random.rand(50, 28,28)
arr2 = arr.reshape(50,28*28)

print(arr2.shape) # (50, 784)
```